# Making changes in Installed Package

Tags: managed-package

While installing a package link, I have selected the option **Install for Admins Only** and now I would w ant to have it available for the other users (All Users) as well. So, is there any way through which I could achieve this.

Basically, I wanted this as I have got Customer Portal enabled and I want those users also to have the ability to access this objects (those which are given to only Admins during Package installation).

Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

There is not a quick way to solve this. You should manually grant all needed permissions to the profile that was not included while setting security,  during the installation . (in this case, all profiles) , such as object access, FLS,  Classes and Pages access, App access (if package contains any).

Another way to copy the configurations from one profile to another is to use the Force.com IDE to compare a profile that you mapped during installation/upgrade to one that was created post installation/upgrade. Also, when you clone a profile, it will automatically carry any permissions that you may have mapped during that installation and upgrade process.

Comment: This is a pain point with managing packages, if you haven't set up too much data etc. in objects provided by the package then the easiest way is to just uninstall and reinstall it.